# Collect sub tree nodes as separate lists with Neo4j

Tags: database, graph, neo4j

I'm trying to create a cypher which collects  subtrees nodes (these subtree nodes are of type Story) and returns them as a separate list. Each tree starts with a family a node, is connected to  user(s) node(s), which is then connected in turn to story node(s).

To clarify, there are multiple trees, I'm trying to collect all the Story nodes, in a structure as follows:

```
{
FamilyOne: Stories:[...],
FamilyTwo: Stories:[...]
}
```

[Here is what the database structure looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSeRl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
MATCH (f:Family)
CALL {
 WITH f
 MATCH (f)<-[*]-(s:Story)
 RETURN f, collect(DISTINCT s) as Stories
}
RETURN f.name as family, Stories
```

Though that gets you a family per row (I don't know what your properties are so I'm guessing), and the stories per family.

If you want a map structure back with the family name as a key, then you need APOC Procedures:

```
MATCH (f:Family)
CALL {
 WITH f
 MATCH (f)<-[*]-(s:Story)
 WITH f, collect(DISTINCT s) as Stories
 RETURN [f.name, f {Stories}] as familyInfo
}
WITH collect(familyInfo) as familyData
RETURN apoc.map.fromPairs(familyData) as results
```

Another approach is to try APOC path expanders to get the stories:

```
MATCH (f:Family)
CALL {
 WITH f
 CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(f, {labelFilter:'/Story', relationshipFilter:'<'}) YIELD node as s
 WITH f, collect(s) as Stories
 RETURN [f.name, f {Stories}] as familyInfo
}
WITH collect(familyInfo) as familyData
RETURN apoc.map.fromPairs(familyData) as results
```

Comment: Hey! First off thanks so much for responding and giving such a thorough  response, very much appreciated.  When I tried your first solution, I kept getting 'variable f already defined'
here is the exact message:
 Variable `f` already declared (line 1, column 8 (offset: 7))
"MATCH (f:Family)"

Comment: Both queries compile for me, so either you're using a version of Neo4j < 4.1.x, or you modified the query in some way (maybe you tried to return `f` from the subquery...you can't do that because `f` is already in scope for the row).